# Conway's game of life algorithm error

Tags: java, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

This is the code. The game works as long as I don't declare the GameBoard and CopyBoard manually and have the user submit the heights and widths.

Whys is the algorithm only working for the first coordinate, but after that it skips over the rest of the code, so automatically it will display an empty board?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

int tracker = 0, neighbors = 0, answer = 0, height = 0, width = 0;
int widthAlg = width - 1;
int heightAlg = height - 1;

Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println(" [1]: Still life \n [2]: Oscillate \n [3]: Cool Game 1 \n [4]: Cool Game 2");
answer = kb.nextInt();

height = 3;
width = 4;
boolean GameBoard[][] = new boolean[height][width];
GameBoard[0][0] = true;
GameBoard[0][1] = true;
GameBoard[1][0] = true;
GameBoard[1][3] = true;
GameBoard[2][1] = true;
GameBoard[2][2] = true;
boolean CopyBoard[][] = new boolean[height][width];

System.out.println("\n\nThis is the original gameboard");
//display of the gameboard
String[][] Display = new String[height][width];
for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < GameBoard[i].length; j++) {
        if (GameBoard[i][j]) {
            Display[i][j] = "*";
        } else {
            Display[i][j] = "-";
        }
        System.out.print(Display[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
};

    String answer1;



    //algorithm
    do{
tracker++;
System.out.print("\nYou have gone " + tracker + " time(s)");
for(int i =0; i < GameBoard.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < GameBoard[i].length; j++){
   if(i == 0 && j == 0){
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if( i == 0 && j >= 1 && j < widthAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if(i == 0 && j == widthAlg){
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if( i >= 1 && i < heightAlg && j == 0 ){
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
   }

    else if( i >= 1 && i < heightAlg && j >= 1 && j < widthAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if( i > 0 && i < heightAlg && j == widthAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i+1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if( i==0 && j == heightAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
   }
   else if( i == heightAlg && j >= 1 && j < widthAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j+1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i][j+1])        {neighbors++;}
   }

   else if( i == heightAlg  && j == widthAlg ){
       if(GameBoard[i][j-1])        {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j-1])      {neighbors++;}
       if(GameBoard[i-1][j])        {neighbors++;}
   }
            //checks the rules to see who survived 
                //and placing the answer in the CopyBoard
                if (GameBoard[i][j]) {
                    if (neighbors >= 2 && neighbors <= 3) {
                        CopyBoard[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        CopyBoard[i][j] = false;
                    }
                } else if (!GameBoard[i][j]) {
                    if (neighbors == 3) {
                        CopyBoard[i][j] = true;
                    } else {
                        CopyBoard[i][j] = false;
                    }
                }
                neighbors = 0;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        //display copyboard
        for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < GameBoard[i].length; j++) {
                if (CopyBoard[i][j]) {
                    Display[i][j] = "*";
                } else {
                    Display[i][j] = "-";
                }
                System.out.print(Display[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Would you like to go again? If yes press \'Y\', else press anything else.");
        answer1 = keyboard.next().toUpperCase();
        if (answer1.toUpperCase().charAt(0) == 'Y')//;
        {   //if he wants to go again copy the results to the original gameboard and repeat.
            for (int i = 0; i < GameBoard.length; i++) {
                System.arraycopy(CopyBoard[i], 0, GameBoard[i], 0, GameBoard[i].length);
            }
        }
    } while (answer1.charAt(0) == 'Y');

}
```

}

Comment: What language is that?  It seems like you ought to reserve one of the tags to identify the language.

Comment: Please, break your code into smaller methods. This is almost impossible to read. At least separate the game logic and the input/startup logic.

Comment: What language is this? That would help

Comment: its java,sorry ill try to clean up the code

Comment: The inconsistent indentation also makes it more difficult to read the code.  If you fix that, you will almost certainly get some insight as to why any given block of code is being skipped.

Answer (score 3):

I think part of your problem, at least, is that these lines...

```
int widthAlg = width - 1;
int heightAlg = height - 1;
```

... appear *before* the lines where width and height are set to their actual values.  The values of widthAlg and heightAlg are therefore always `-1`.

If you step through the program using a debugger, logic errors like this will become clear very quickly.